# Why I am getting access denied exception when trying to set useraccountcontrolflag?

Tags: c#, active-directory

C# code 
following is my C# code which is throwing error access denied.

```
const int iFlag = 0x1000; //WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT
string sCommonName = "CN=" + sMachineName;

DirectoryEntry deComputer = deOU.Children.Add(sCommonName, "computer");
deComputer.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = sMachineName + "$";
deComputer.CommitChanges();

deComputer.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = iFlag;
deComputer.CommitChanges(); // access denied exception.
```

I tried to write powershell script to set it but didnt get success.

EDIT : other flag I am bel to set.i.e

const int iFlag = 544; // success

only problem is in iflag = 0x1000

Comment: Is that code running on a windows service or windows application?

Comment: Did you set your ServiceProcessInstaller object's account property to ServiceAccount.LocalSystem in your Installer.cs file?

Comment: I have no idea on this. how to check?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? My expectation is that this can only be set during the domain join process which is why you're getting the error.

Comment: it is our automation where we create few account and test our logic. this code set all accounts before automation starts testing logic.